# Python: Issue when a greater than or equal to statement is satisfied also prints out more

Tags: python

My code:

```
if year >= 2101:
    print('Distant Future')
if year >= 2001:
    print('21st century')
if year >= 1901:
    print('20th century')
else:
    print('Long ago')
```

Issue:
when year = 2001
I get both 21st century and 20th. I obviously just want the 21st to print out.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `elif` statement.

Essentially, with your current code, if the first `if` fails, then the next one will be evaluated. Now ALSO if the first `if` **succeeds**, then the next one will still be evaluated as well. You want to exit after succeeding the first time.

Try this:

```
if year >= 2101:
    print('Distant Future')
elif year >= 2001:
    print('21st century')
elif year >= 1901:
    print('20th century')
else:
    print('Long ago')
```

Comment: No problem. Please don't forget to upvote if you think the answer was written well and mark as "accepted answer" if it worked for you!

Comment: @CapnJack OP unable to upvote because has less than 15 reputation

Answer (score 0):

A much shorter one-liner:

```
print(['Distant Future','21st century','20th century','Long ago'][[year>=2101,year>=2001,year>=1901].index(True)])
```

**Demo:**

```
year=2018
print(['Distant Future','21st century','20th century','Long ago'][[year>=2101,year>=2001,year>=1901,year<1901].index(True)])
```

Output:

```
21st century
```